# Unrecognized selector sent to instance in simple code

Tags: ios, swift

Could I ask below problem?

> [Quiz.ViewController showNextQuesttionWithSender:]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7ff0b150c720

Was occurred at the below code. And I don't understand what is mean.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 

    @IBOutlet var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var answerLabel: UILabel!

    let questions: [String] = ["birth daut?", "name?", "birth son?"]
    let answers: [String] = ["12wol4il", "yuha", "54"]
    var currentQuestionIndex: Int = 0

    @IBAction func showNextQuestion(sender: AnyObject) {
        currentQuestionIndex+=1
        if currentQuestionIndex == questions.count
        {
            currentQuestionIndex = 0
        }

        let question: String = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
        questionLabel.text = question
        answerLabel.text = "???"
    }

    @IBAction func showAnswer(sender: AnyObject) {
        let answer: String = answers[currentQuestionIndex]
        answerLabel.text = answer
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionLabel.text = questions[currentQuestionIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: check outlet connection in storyboard for this action button.

Comment: You might have showNextQuesttionWithSender connected on storyboard but actual method is not in controller, Check connection on button from Storyboard and remove showNextQuesttionWithSender from button's connection.

Comment: code formatting

Comment: Unrecognized selector means something tried to call a function but that function does not exist. Please attach more of the debug output. It tells you which function it could not find.

Comment: Press ⇧⌘F, copy&paste (not type!) the wrong selector into the search field, press return. Click on the search result and fix the error (typo).

Answer (score 1):

You have just a typo in your storyboard.

showNextQuesttion should be showNextQuestion